# Running a web test server with Ubuntu

Tags: apache2, webserver, lamp, tomcat

I have typically used XAMPP on my windows PC for web development testing.  This afternoon I plan to add [LAMP](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies) to my Ubuntu.  I would also like to try and install [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) but I am not familiar if

1. Can this be done in Ubuntu 12.04?
2. Is there any solid documentation for testing and running?

I did not find anything from my searches here so if this has been asked please close.  Also, if you can suggest a better tutorial for the LAMP install I would greatly appreciate it.  This will be for local testing, too.

Comment: You may wish to check this out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel

Comment: I think it will be easier for you to not focus to much on lamp, but focus on getting apache running on your desktop. I found that to be easier.

Comment: @Private Do you have a suggestion then on the best way to just install Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question in hopes to figure out a quality solution but it would appear all we should do is Google our questions instead of posting threads that may benefit others in the future.  That being said I shall go through the following and test.

Hope this helps the next person:

- [Ubuntu Server Guide, chapter LAMP](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lamp-applications.html)
- [ApacheMySQLPHP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)
- [How to Install And Configure Apache In    Ubuntu](http://maketecheasier.com/install-and-configure-apache-in-ubuntu/2011/03/09)
- [How to Install Apache Tomcat on Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-on-ubuntu-12-04)
- [ApacheTomcat5 Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheTomcat5)
- [Installing Tomcat 6 on Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/installing-tomcat-6-on-ubuntu/) [Apache Tomcat](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/tomcat.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a web server built into Ubuntu, you don't need to install anything. PHP does not ship with Ubuntu, but you can install it easily using Software Center.

### How to use Python to run a CGI web server

Simply make a new directory (lets call it `www_playground`) enter it using the terminal. Make a new directory in the directory called `cgi-bin`. Now make a text file called `hello.php` in the `cgi-bin` directory. Write this into the file and make it executable:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
echo "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; /* DON'T TOUCH THIS unless you know what you're doing */
?>
<!doctype html>
<html><body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p>How are you? The time is <?php echo date("r"); ?>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Now, in the terminal (which is in the `www_playground` directory), write `python -m CGIHTTPServer` and <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>. The server will start, leave it running in the terminal in the background for as long as you want.

You can now open a web browser and go to `http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/hello.php`, and you should see the web page we just created.